# File naming inside a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

Please have a look on the following Minimal Working Example (MWE)

```
import numpy as np
T_val = np.linspace(100,200,15)
for i,T in enumerate(T_val):
    ut_file_name = 'kappaFunction_P_E_%2d.pdf' % i
    print out_file_name
```

The output for this MWE coming like:

> .
>   .
>   kappaFunction_P_E_ 7.pdf
>   kappaFunction_P_E_ 8.pdf
>   kappaFunction_P_E_ 9.pdf
>   kappaFunction_P_E_10.pdf
>   kappaFunction_P_E_11.pdf
>   kappaFunction_P_E_12.pdf
>   .
>   .

What I intended to get is

> ... kappaFunction_P_E_08.pdf, kappaFunction_P_E_09.pdf,  kappaFunction_P_E_10.pdf....

Instead of prepending **0** before the single digit number it is leaving a space. How can we get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `enumerate` since your are only using the index.
And for your format to work as expected, you need to use `%02d` to get the `0` before:

```
import numpy as np
T_val = np.linspace(100,200,15)
for i in range(len(T_val)):
    ut_file_name = 'kappaFunction_P_E_%02d.pdf' % i
    print out_file_name
```

Comment: Hi.. 
Thanks. In MWE I am using only the index. But in my actual script, I have to use the values.

Comment: I was expecting that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ut_file_name = 'kappaFunction_P_E_{:0>2}.pdf'.format(i)
```

Your should use format(). You can reference from https://pyformat.info/ or docs from https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `0` to the format

```
... %02d.pdf' % i
```

that will print 07, 08, 09, etc.